# Add a comment to an action/component in Release Management

Tags: tfs, ms-release-management

I'm using TFS 2013 Update 3 and Release Management 2013 with Update 3 (agent-based templates).

In the Release Management client, I'd find very useful the ability to add a comment for any action/component (or even a group of them) that is part of a deployment sequence. This is because often it's obvious what an action/component does (e.g. "Move File or Folder"), but it might be useful to know why that is done, also in the context of that particular deployment sequence.

I haven't found a way to achieve that, is it actually possible?

If not, do you have any alternative solution or do you know if a similar feature is available in newer
versions?

Comment: You should switch to vNext Templates and move all of the heavy lifting to PowerShell, which supports all the comments and notes you like..

Answer (score 2):

One thing you can try (but I am not sure if Agent-based Update 3 allows it) is to rename the action/component once dropped on the canvas. I know vNext templates allows it, and some earlier versions of Agent-based allowed it (but not the recent one... it seems to be broken).

Another less optimal option would be to add a parameter (which would be ignored during the actual deployment) - call it 'Notes' or similar - and just fill its value with the description of what this action/component does. It is less obvious and you may need to scroll to see it when you have many params, but it would be available. Also, this would only work with custom actions and components.

Last option would be to put your action/component (or group of) inside a 'Sequence'. You can rename those by clicking on the name. That would give some context on what that action(s) does.

Comment: You can't rename actions in agent-based templates, even in update 4. You can rename sequences, manual interventions, and parallel blocks. Nothing else. vNext templates are a different story.